Installing 2sxc on DNN downgrade from Evoq Content
As the title says, we have a DNN Evoq Content site that we downgraded to Platform. We want to rebuild the Evoq Content Visualizer in 2sxc apps. Installing 2sxc wasn't the issue. When I drop the app module on the page I see "Something went really wrong in view.ascx - check error logs".
Looking at the logs I see these two errors below. What's also odd is I don't have a C:\Projects folder on my system.
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - System.Exception: Couldn't load Connection String as SetConnectionString must have been forgotten
   at ToSic.Eav.Internal.Configuration.DbConfiguration.get_ConnectionString() in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\Internal\Configuration\DbConfiguration.cs:line 14
   at ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc.Models.EavDbContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc\Models\EavDbContext.cs:line 15
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.EntryWithoutDetectChanges[TEntity](TEntity entity)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState[TEntity](TEntity entity, EntityState entityState)
   at ToSic.Eav.Repository.Efc.Parts.DbZone.AddZone(String name) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Repository.Efc\Parts\DbZone.cs:line 10
   at ToSic.Eav.Apps.Internal.Work.ZoneCreator.Create(String name) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Apps\Eav.Apps.Internal\Work\Zones\ZoneCreator.cs:line 16
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Run.DnnZoneMapper.GetZoneId(Int32 siteId) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Core\Dnn\Run\DnnZoneMapper.cs:line 40
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Context.DnnSite.get_ZoneId() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Core\Dnn\Context\DnnSite.cs:line 249
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Context.DnnModule.get_BlockIdentifier() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Core\Dnn\Context\DnnModule.cs:line 79
   at ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.Internal.BlockFromModule.Init(IContextOfBlock ctx) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Blocks\Internal\BlockOfModule.cs:line 19
   at ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.Internal.ModuleAndBlockBuilder.BuildBlock[TPlatformModule](TPlatformModule module, Nullable`1 page) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Blocks\Internal\ModuleAndBlockBuilder.cs:line 37
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.<get_Block>b__7_1() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.cs:line 45
   at ToSic.Lib.Logging.LogCallBaseExtensions.DoInTimer[TResult](ILogCall logCall, Func`1 action) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Lib.Core\Logging\LogCall\LogCallBaseExtensions.cs:line 24
   at ToSic.Lib.Logging.ILog_Properties.Getter[TProperty](ILog log, Func`1 getter, Boolean timer, Boolean enabled, String message, String parameters, String cPath, String cName, Int32 cLine) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Lib.Core\Logging\Log\ILog_Properties.cs:line 38
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.get_Block() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.cs:line 45
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.InitModuleActions() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.menu.cs:line 39
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.<get_ModuleActions>b__31_0() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.menu.cs:line 28


DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - FriendlyMessage="Error: App is currently unavailable." ctrl="ASP.desktopmodules_tosic_sexycontent_view_ascx" exc="System.Exception: Error - can't find 2sxc instance configuration. Probably trying to show an app or content that has been deleted or not yet installed. You may also have EnterpriseCMS features enabled but are missing the license activation (but this is super rare). 
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Install.DnnReadyCheckTurbo.EnsureSiteAndAppFoldersAreReady(PortalModuleBase module, IBlock block) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Core\Dnn\Install\DnnReadyCheckTurbo.cs:line 36
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Page_Load>b__2() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.cs:line 102
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.TryCatchAndLogToDnn[TResult](Func`1 action) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.Errors.cs:line 20"


It looks like you are missing something configuration wise within 2sxc, the path noted is from where/when 2sxc was compiled

@MitchelSellers I pulled the latest ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.18.02.00_Install.zip from github to install. Is this something happening during the install?

So first of all, the messages saying C:\Projects\... are just to indicate in what line of code something broke. This is from where 2sxc was compiled, you won't have that folder.
Note that various companies have 2sxc running in Evoq, so it does work. I'm not sure what's wrong in your system...
It says it can't find the connection string.
My guess is that either

You did something special, so the connection string is not in the normal place in the web.config
Something at startup didn't run properly, resulting in the connection string not being picked up early on.

Best dig a bit deeper. Also check out the 2sxc-insights, as they contain logs from the very start - so anything failing at load time should show up there.
